# How can I run a if else function based on results of bool value

Tags: ios, swift

Using the results of JSON to either run a function or display an alert.

First a function called `CheckStruct()` should run.

**The results of this function is either true or false using the following structure:**

```
struct CheckStruct: Codable {
    let error: Bool?
}
```

If the function result is Optional(false) one thing should happen.

If the function result is Optional(true) an alert should appear.

**The following is JSONFunc()**

```
private func JSONFunc() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example.php"),
        let value = name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "number=\(number)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let myData= try JSONDecoder().decode(CheckStruct.self, from:data)

             print(myData.error)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: print your checkStruct code since is the response of the request,

Comment: My bad checkStruct is the top structure

Comment: Your question is unclear, and part of what you say makes no sense. You say a function called `CheckStruct()` should run, but what you posted was a struct that does not include any functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let myData = try JSONDecoder().decode(CheckStruct.self, from:data) 
if  myData.error == true {
  // true
}
else {
   // false or nil 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private func JSONFunc() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example.php"),
        let value = name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "number=\(number)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let myData = try JSONDecoder().decode(CheckStruct.self, from:data)
            guard let error = myData.error else {return}
            if error {
                //dotour stuff
            }else{
                //do other stuff
            }
            //or this code using ternary operator
         //   error == true ? /*do stuff here*/: //do another stuff if false
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()
}enter code here
```